# Dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on dell Inspiron 15R 3521 in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 3521 Laptop come with windows 8 in built.
I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 in UEFI mode to dual boot.
I have read to much on this and looks like every machine or laptop behaves in different way due to Difference in their UEFI architecture with their processor.
Please help me in this regard so that I don't want to screwed up with my current windowds 8 behaviour.

Guys your help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on Dell Inspiron 15R 3521. I tried it on my Dell 15R and it works well. http://itechwik.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode-on-your-computer-or-laptop-2728/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.